# How to change the default Pydantic error message using FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

Is there any way to change the default response from Pydantic so that `"msg"` is `"message"`?

```
{
    "detail": [
        {
            "loc": [
                "body",
                "password"
            ],
            "msg": "Password should at least 8 characters long.",
            "type": "value_error"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Maybe try this https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/model_config/

Comment: @Willow I don't think this changes the "msg" key

Comment: What you call "the default response from pydantic" in your question seems to be a `ValidationError`, but you show what seems to be JSON. I think your question should be improved because it depends on how you come up with that JSON from a `ValidationError`. Check [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Are you using FastAPI? That kind of response is what FastAPI, by default, returns as a response when the request results in a Pydantic ValidationError: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/#override-request-validation-exceptions

Comment: @GinoMempin Yes I am using fastapi

Comment: @GinoMempin Is it possible to capture multiple validator error messages in one go when using fastapi and pydantic? Please see my other question

Comment: @Chris no, in my case I have multiple requirements for the password field, for example it must be greater than 8 characters, must contain 1 upper case, 1 lower case. If I use a custom validator(), then I have not figured out how to test all conditions against the provided value in the request and return 1 list of errors like fastapi does if fields are missing in the request. Instead, Python is raising an error on any failed condition and immediately returning the ValueError exception.

Comment: @Chris this is what I'm really after, to solve: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71905671/pydantic-cycle-through-all-validators-even-if-one-fails-fastapi/

Answer (score 5):

That looks like a JSON response and Pydantic by itself **does not give out a JSON** response for `ValidationError`'s. It should just be a regular `raise`-d `Exception` like this:

```
In [2]: from pydantic import BaseModel, constr

In [3]: class Credentials(BaseModel):
   ...:     password: constr(min_length=8)
   ...: 

In [4]: Credentials(password="xyz")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValidationError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [4], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 Credentials(password="xyz")

...

ValidationError: 1 validation error for Credentials
password
  ensure this value has at least 8 characters (type=value_error.any_str.min_length; limit_value=8)
```

I think you are using FastAPI ([which has Pydantic integration](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/features/#pydantic-features)) and this JSON response is actually FastAPI's built-in error response when the request has `ValidationError`'s, as described in the [FastAPI docs on Handling Errors](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/). I can replicate a similar error format with this example:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from pydantic import BaseModel, constr

class Credentials(BaseModel):
    password: constr(min_length=8)

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/login")
async def login(credentials: Credentials):
    print(credentials)  # This is just as an example!
    return JSONResponse(status_code=200)
```

```json
$ curl -s --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --data '{"password":"xyz"}' http://localhost:8000/login | jq
{
  "detail": [
    {
      "loc": [
        "body",
        "password"
      ],
      "msg": "ensure this value has at least 8 characters",
      "type": "value_error.any_str.min_length",
      "ctx": {
        "limit_value": 8
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

To change the response body, check the FastAPI docs on [Use the RequestValidationError body](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/#use-the-requestvalidationerror-body) that shows you can access the default `detail` list of errors, which you can then edit or copy over to a customized details list, and then set it as the `content` of the JSON error response.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, status
from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder
from fastapi.exceptions import RequestValidationError
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from pydantic import BaseModel, constr

class Credentials(BaseModel):
    password: constr(min_length=8)

app = FastAPI()

@app.exception_handler(RequestValidationError)
async def validation_exception_handler(request: Request, exc: RequestValidationError):
    # Get the original 'detail' list of errors
    details = exc.errors()
    modified_details = []
    # Replace 'msg' with 'message' for each error
    for error in details:
        modified_details.append(
            {
                "loc": error["loc"],
                "message": error["msg"],
                "type": error["type"],
            }
        )
    return JSONResponse(
        status_code=status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY,
        content=jsonable_encoder({"detail": modified_details}),
    )


@app.post("/login")
async def login(credentials: Credentials):
    print(credentials)  # Just as an example!
    return JSONResponse(status_code=200)
```

```json
$ curl -s --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --data '{"password":"xyz"}' http://localhost:8000/login | jq
{
  "detail": [
    {
      "loc": [
        "body",
        "password"
      ],
      "message": "ensure this value has at least 8 characters",
      "type": "value_error.any_str.min_length"
    }
  ]
}
```

Of course, you can also simply just define your own custom `content` and `JSONResponse`.

Comment: Is it possible to capture multiple validator error messages in one go when using fastapi and pydantic? Please see my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71905671/pydantic-cycle-through-all-validators-even-if-one-fails-fastapi/71914006?noredirect=1#comment127111100_71914006

Comment: @dataviews I am AFK now, I'll take a look when I have time, but if I remember correctly, all the validation errors are _already_ returned in the response. It's why `detail` is a list, it should be a list of errors. At least that's what happens on my app, where I use 1 model for the entire request.

Comment: I think that is the case if you don't use a validator(). When you see my other post it may make sense what I am trying to do there. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Building upon the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72003724/17865804) to your question, you could use a [validation exception handler](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/#use-the-requestvalidationerror-body), as shown below. Related answers on how to customise FastAPI's or Pydantic's error message can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71682274/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71800464/17865804), well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73151350/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70954531/17865804).

```py
from fastapi import Request, status
from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder
from fastapi.exceptions import RequestValidationError
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse

@app.exception_handler(RequestValidationError)
async def validation_exception_handler(request: Request, exc: RequestValidationError):
    for error in exc.errors(): 
        error['message'] = error.pop('msg')
    
    return JSONResponse(content=jsonable_encoder({"detail": exc.errors()}), status_code=status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)
```

##### Output:

```json
{
    "detail": [
        {
            "loc": [
                "body",
                "password"
            ],
            "message": "Password should at least 8 characters long.",
            "type": "value_error"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1- Add Config class to the schema that inheritance from BaseModel.

2- In Config add `value_msg_templates` dict and start to customize messages: `key` is error type and `value` is your new messages for this type.

```
class UserAuth(BaseModel):
    email: EmailStr = Field(..., description="user email", example="userTest@example.com",)
    username: str = Field(..., min_length=5, max_length=10, description="user username", example="userTest",)
    password: str = Field(..., description="user password", example="Tyu*&^54",)


    class Config:
        error_msg_templates = {
            'value_error.email': 'email address is not valid.',
        }
```

where is types:

[image]

3- add these lines to main.py or app.py file:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, status, HTTPException, Response
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder
from fastapi.exceptions import RequestValidationError
from pydantic import ValidationError
from pydantic.error_wrappers import ErrorWrapper 
.
.
.
app = FastAPI()
.
.
.
@app.exception_handler(RequestValidationError)
async def http_exception_accept_handler(request: Request, exc: RequestValidationError) -> Response:
    raw_errors = exc.raw_errors
    error_wrapper: ErrorWrapper = raw_errors[0]
    validation_error: ValidationError = error_wrapper.exc
    overwritten_errors = validation_error.errors()
    return JSONResponse(status_code=status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY,
                        content={"detail": jsonable_encoder(overwritten_errors)},
                        )
.
.
.
```

Finish :)

Answer (score 1):

All the answers that you have been given are correct, but they have only one little tiny problem.
In your Api documentation under the `/docs` or `/redoc` path, the `ValidationError` and the `HTTPValidationError`
are still displayed as before.

The `ValidationError` will return whenever you have conversion error in your api path and `fastapi` will return a `RequestValidationError` itself. The one that you handle it by defining a custom exception handler.

The `HTTPValidationError` will retuen whenever you raise a `HTTPException` in your api.

Unfortunately, until this version of the framework (v0.92.0), there is still no proper and clean way to solve this problem (according to the discussion that happened [here](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/discussions/9061)) so to fix that, you have to override two variables of `fastapi.openapi.utils` module :

`validation_error_definition` and `validation_error_response_definition`.

If you check them, they're just a simple and hardcoded dictionary. You can either change these two variables manually, in your main file or you can define a `Pydantic` model to handle your errors and use It's `schema()` method to get the `openapi schema`. I prefer second way

```
from datetime import datetime

from pydantic import BaseModel
from fastapi.openapi import utils


class CustomRequestValidationError(BaseModel):
    message: str
    type: str
    time: int
    extra: dict


validation_schema = CustomRequestValidationError.schema()

custom_validation_error_definition = dict(validation_schema)

validation_schema.update({"title": "HTTPValidationError"})

custom_validation_error_response_definition = dict(validation_schema)



utils.validation_error_definition = custom_validation_error_definition
utils.validation_error_response_definition = custom_validation_error_response_definition
```

The point is that in this method we have to use several variables. If the `schema()` method is used directly, by changing the dictionary, the previous values will also change