# How to customize validation error message in FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi

```py
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, Query

app = FastAPI()
 
@app.get("/")
async def read_items(name:str= Query(max_length=5,error_message='name too long'),
                     age:int= Query(error_message='age need intger')):
   return '...'
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app="main:app", host="localhost", port=5000)
```

If I type `http://localhost:5000/?name=asdfasdfasdfasdreerer&age=s`, the error message would be as shown below:

> {"detail":[{"loc":["query","name"],"msg":"ensure this value has at
> most 5
> characters","type":"value_error.any_str.max_length","ctx":{"limit_value":5}},{"loc":["query","age"],"msg":"value
> is not a valid integer","type":"type_error.integer"}]}

**However, I would like to display my own custom error message:**

> {"detail":[{"loc":["query","name"],"msg":"name too
> long","type":"value_error.any_str.max_length","ctx":{"limit_value":5}},{"loc":["query","age"],"msg":"age
> need integer","type":"type_error.integer"}]}

**'error message' is a assumed property**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the default Pydantic error message using FastAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71895606/how-to-change-the-default-pydantic-error-message-using-fastapi)

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71682274/17865804) most likely offers solutions best suited to your problem, as you seem to be looking to customise the error for a specific route only. Some related answers can also be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75545471/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71800464/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70954531/17865804)

Comment: In fact.These answers can work but all not I want. I want something like  c# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-7.0  [Required(ErrorMessage = "wrong message")],  It very easy to custom own error message.