# Awaiting request.json() in FastAPI hangs forever

Tags: python, fastapi, freeze, starlette, exceptionhandler

I added the exception handling as given here (https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/discussions/6678) to my code but I want to print the complete request body to see the complete content. However, when I await the `request.json()` it never terminates. `request.json()` returns a coroutine, so I need to wait for the coroutine to complete before printing the result.
How can I print the content of the request in case an invalid request was sent to the endpoint?

Code example from github with 2 changes by me in the error handler and a simple endpoint.

```py
import logging
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, status
from fastapi.exceptions import RequestValidationError
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()


@app.exception_handler(RequestValidationError)
async def validation_exception_handler(
    request: Request, exc: RequestValidationError
) -> JSONResponse:
    exc_str = f"{exc}".replace("\n", " ").replace("   ", " ")
    logging.error(f"{request}: {exc_str}")
    body = await request.json()  # This line was added by me and never completes
    logging.error(body)  # This line was added by me
    content = {"status_code": 10422, "message": exc_str, "data": None}
    return JSONResponse(
        content=content, status_code=status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY
    )


class User(BaseModel):
    name: str


@app.post("/")
async def test(body: User) -> User:
    return body
```

Comment: You might find the following answers helpful: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73464007/17865804), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70954531/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71682274/17865804)

Comment: Thanks, using `exc.body` instead of `request.json()` seems to work. However, I still don't understand why `await request.json()` never terminates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When `await`ing `request.json`, you are trying to read the `request` body (**not** the `response` body, as you may have assumed) out from stream; however, this operation has **already** taken place in your API endpoint (behind the scenes, in your case). Hence, calling `await request.json()` is allowed only once in the API's request life-cycle, and attempting reading it again will keep on waiting for it indefinitely (since reading the request body got exhausted), which causes the hanging issue. You may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73464007/17865804) helpful as well, regarding reading/logging the `request` body (and/or `response` body) in a FastAPI/Starlette middleware, before passing the request to the endpoint.

As for getting the error body from the response in the `RequestValidationError` exception handler, you would not need to read the `request` body, but the `response` body and you can do that by calling `exc.body`, instead of `request.json()`, as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70954531/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71682274/17865804). Please refer to those answers for more details.

### Example

```py
from fastapi.exceptions import RequestValidationError

@app.exception_handler(RequestValidationError)
async def validation_exception_handler(request: Request, exc: RequestValidationError):
    return JSONResponse(
        status_code=status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY,
        content=jsonable_encoder({"detail": exc.errors(),  # optionally include the errors
                "body": exc.body,
                 "custom msg": {"Your error message"}}),
    )
```