# python avoid catching specific exception

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi

I am tasked to debug an API. One of its endpoints handles creating and updating some resource, and I want to raise an appropriate exception if the resource cannot be updated correctly. I was handed a function that looks like so:

```py
from fastapi import APIRouter, HTTPException
router = APIRouter()

@router.post("/")
async def create_resource(body:dict) -> dict:
    try:
        ...
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="data not found")
```

One possible error inside the function would be better explained with a `409 response`, so I added the exception as shown below:

```py
@router.post("/")
async def create_resource(body:dict) -> dict:
    try:
        ...

        if bad_condition:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=409, detail="data points already exist")

    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="data not found")
```

From what I can gather, the broad `try/except` clause is catching my error and raising a `404 response` regardless. I want to be able to raise the 409 error instead of a generic 404 without tinkering too much with the function. What is the cleanest way to raise this error without refactoring the function itself?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71800464/17865804) answer your question?

Comment: Related answers can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70954531/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71682274/17865804) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python [you can specify multiple except blocks](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions), the first matching one of which will execute. You could therefore `except` then re-`raise` all `HTTPException`s to avoid replacing them with 404s

```
@router.post("/")
async def create_resource(body:dict) -> dict:
    try:
        ...

        if bad_condition:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=409, detail="data points already exist")
    except HTTPException as e:
        raise e
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="data not found")
```

this would mean if you had any `HTTPException`s they'd still be raised but anything else would be replaced by the 404 `HTTPException`.