# How to go through all Pydantic validators even if one fails, and then raise multiple ValueErrors in a FastAPI response?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, pydantic

Is it possible to call all validators to get back a full list of errors?

```
@validator('password', always=True)
def validate_password1(cls, value):
    password = value.get_secret_value()

    min_length = 8
    if len(password) < min_length:
        raise ValueError('Password must be at least 8 characters long.')

    return value

@validator('password', always=True)
def validate_password2(cls, value):
    password = value.get_secret_value()

    if not any(character.islower() for character in password):
        raise ValueError('Password should contain at least one lowercase character.')

    return value
```

The current behavior seems to call one validator at a time.

My Pydantic class:

```
class User(BaseModel):
    email: EmailStr
    password: SecretStr
```

If I did not include the `email`, or `password`, field on a request then I would get both validation failures in an array, which is what I want to do for the `password` field, but the current behavior seems to call one, and if it fails then throws the error immediately.

Comment: @OrenIshShalom I cant seem to get pydantic or fastapi to return all errors in one go

Comment: You can use one main validator which checks other validator conditions.

Comment: @stuck do you have an example, or could you share some quick sudo code of what you mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't raise multiple [Validation](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/) errors/exceptions for a specific field in the way this is demonstrated in your question. Suggested solutions are given below.

### Option 1

###### Update

Note that in Pydantic V2, `@validator` has been deprecated and was replaced by `@field_validator`. Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71258131/17865804) for more details and examples.

###### Original answer

Concatenate error messages using a single variable, and raise the `ValueError` once at the end (if errors occured):

```py
@validator('password', always=True)
def validate_password1(cls, value):
    password = value.get_secret_value()
    min_length = 8
    errors = ''
    if len(password) < min_length:
        errors += 'Password must be at least 8 characters long. '
    if not any(character.islower() for character in password):
        errors += 'Password should contain at least one lowercase character.'
    if errors:
        raise ValueError(errors)
        
    return value
```

In the case that all the above conditional statements are met, the output will be:

```json
{
  "detail": [
    {
      "loc": [
        "body",
        "password"
      ],
      "msg": "Password must be at least 8 characters long. Password should contain at least one lowercase character.",
      "type": "value_error"
    }
  ]
}
```

### Option 2

###### Update

In Pydantic V2, `ErrorWrapper` has been removed—have a look at [Migration Guide](https://docs.pydantic.dev/dev-v2/migration/#removed-in-pydantic-v2). If one would like to implement this on their own, please have a look at Pydantic V1.9 [`error_wrappers.py`](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/1.9.X-fixes/pydantic/error_wrappers.py). Additionally, `@validator` has been deprecated and was replaced by `@field_validator`. Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71258131/17865804) for more details and examples.

###### Original answer

Raise [`ValidationError`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#error-handling) directly, using a list of [`ErrorWrapper`](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/blob/master/pydantic/error_wrappers.py#L28) class.

```py
from pydantic import ValidationError
from pydantic.error_wrappers import ErrorWrapper

@validator('password', always=True)
def validate_password1(cls, value):
    password = value.get_secret_value()
    min_length = 8
    errors = []
    if len(password) < min_length:
        errors.append(ErrorWrapper(ValueError('Password must be at least 8 characters long.'), loc=None))
    if not any(character.islower() for character in password):
        errors.append(ErrorWrapper(ValueError('Password should contain at least one lowercase character.'), loc=None))
    if errors:
        raise ValidationError(errors, model=User)
        
    return value
```

Since FastAPI seems to be adding the `loc` attribute itself, `loc` would end up having the `field` name (i.e., `password`) twice, if it was added in the `ErrorWrapper`, using the `loc` attribute (which is a required parameter). Hence, you could leave it empty (using `None`), which you can later remove through a [validation exception handler](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/#use-the-requestvalidationerror-body), as shown below:

```py
from fastapi import Request, status
from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder
from fastapi.exceptions import RequestValidationError
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse

@app.exception_handler(RequestValidationError)
async def validation_exception_handler(request: Request, exc: RequestValidationError):
    for error in exc.errors(): 
        error['loc'] = [x for x in error['loc'] if x]  # remove null attributes
        
    return JSONResponse(content=jsonable_encoder({"detail": exc.errors()}), status_code=status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)
```

In the case that all the above conditional statements are met, the output will be:

```json
{
  "detail": [
    {
      "loc": [
        "body",
        "password"
      ],
      "msg": "Password must be at least 8 characters long.",
      "type": "value_error"
    },
    {
      "loc": [
        "body",
        "password"
      ],
      "msg": "Password should contain at least one lowercase character.",
      "type": "value_error"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: for v2 this does not work anymore.

Comment: A few changes are required in Pydantic v2, but essentially it's a case of switching `ErrorWrapper` for `ValidationError.from_exception_data()`. See the following comment for a comprehensive example, that also validates the model before returning.

https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/discussions/7470#discussioncomment-7028695

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use [Pydantic's validators](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/) like that; it always looks one of them.

To achieve your answer, you can use following 2 methods

1 - You can use one main validator which checks all conditions

```
@validator('password', always=True)
def validate_password(cls, value):
    password = value.get_secret_value()

    validate_password1(password)
    validate_password2(password)

    return value
    
def validate_password1(password):

    min_length = 8
    if len(password) < min_length:
        raise ValueError('Password must be at least 8 characters long.')


def validate_password2(password):

    if not any(character.islower() for character in password):
        raise ValueError('Password should contain at least one lowercase character.')
```

2 - You can use duplicate variable in model to check condition

```
class User(BaseModel):
    email: EmailStr
    password: SecretStr
    password2: SecretStr
```

and obviously, your decorators should be:

```
@validator('password', always=True)
def validate_password1(cls, value):
```

and

```
@validator('password2', always=True)
def validate_password2(cls, value):
```

**UPDATE:** The OP wants to raise all errors, so the updated answer as follows.

In addition to 1st bullet, you may try something like that:

```
@validator('password', always=True)
def validate_password(cls, value):
    password = value.get_secret_value()

    try:
        validate_password1(password)
    except Exception as e:
        print('First error: ' + str(e))
        
    try:
        validate_password2(password)
    except Exception as e:
        print('Second error: ' + str(e))

    return value
    
def validate_password1(password):

    min_length = 8
    if len(password) < min_length:
        raise ValueError('Password must be at least 8 characters long.')


def validate_password2(password):

    if not any(character.islower() for character in password):
        raise ValueError('Password should contain at least one lowercase character.')
```

However, be careful when returning the `value`. You may try to add one more custom exception in your main code.

Comment: I have not tested option 2, but option 1 doesn't work. It still returns the first validation, which is the password length validator @stuck

Comment: You removed `@validator` from other methods, right?

Comment: By the way, I deleted the return statements from validate_password1 and 2

Comment: Does not work. raise returns the first error I believe. I've implemented it as you suggested

Comment: Oh, you want to raise both errors?

Comment: Yep! If possible, I'd like to get all validation errors in one api call

Comment: Well, Instead of raising each of them, you can collect them in a list. Or, you can call the sub-functions inside the try-except block. Because when you "raise" something, it breaks all steps inside the block. I will update the answer.