# Its possible replace the default exception "ValidationError" for another one with more attributes - pydantic?

Tags: python, exception, fastapi, pydantic

I want to create a new exception that extends `ValidationError` and add some attributes and raise this new exception instead of `ValidationError`. I have a model that contains various attributes and I don't want to create a `raise` for each value, because the `ValidationError` already is raised when the value is not filled, for example.

Code example:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Foo(BaseModel):
    number: int

x = Foo()
```

will throw:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/daniel/Projects/clients-safra/source/foo.py", line 7, in <module>
    x = Foo()
  File "/home/daniel/.pyenv/versions/safra-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydantic/main.py", line 406, in __init__
    raise validation_error
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for Foo
number
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

I want to do this:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError


class MyValidationError(ValidationError):
    error-code:str = 'my-code'


class Foo(BaseModel):
    number: int

    # DO ANYTHING TO RAISES `MyValidationError`
    # I THINK SOMETHING ABOUT `class Config`

x = Foo()
```

and expected to raises my exception:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/daniel/Projects/clients-safra/source/foo.py", line 7, in <module>
    x = Foo()
  File "/home/daniel/.pyenv/versions/safra-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydantic/main.py", line 406, in __init__
    raise validation_error
MyValidationError: 1 validation error for Foo
number
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

Comment: Also, please have a look at related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72003724/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72003764/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71682274/17865804)